# How to parse data in JSON and search for multiple patterns or matches?

Tags: python, json, regex, parsing

I have a JSON file that look like this (just an example. The real file is much larger):

```
[
 {
   "Rank": 1,
   "Title": "Impact of Vitamin D on Acute Ischemic Stroke Prognosis",
   "Status": "Completed",
   "Study_Results": "No Results Available",
   "Conditions": "Ischemic Stroke",
   "Interventions": "Diagnostic Test: Vitamin D Level",
   "Locations": "Mansoura University, Mansourah, Dakahlia, Egypt|IQVIA, Basel, Switzerland",
   "URL": "https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT03819452"
 },
 {
   "Rank": 2,
   "Title": "A Randomized Controlled Study of the Effectiveness of Scalp Electroacupuncture in Improving Upper Limb Motor Function in Convalescent Phase of Ischemic Stroke.",
   "Status": "Not yet recruiting",
   "Study_Results": "No Results Available",
   "Conditions": "Ischemic Stroke",
   "Interventions": "Device: scalp electroacupuncture|Device: sham scalp electroacupuncture",
   "Locations": "",
   "URL": "https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT02850198"
 },
 {
   "Rank": 3,
   "Title": "Mesenchymal Stem Cells for The Treatment of Acute Ischemic Stroke",
   "Status": "Not yet recruiting",
   "Study_Results": "No Results Available",
   "Conditions": "Acute Ischemic Stroke",
   "Interventions": "Biological: UMC119-06",
   "Locations": "Taipei Medical University - Shuang Ho Hospital, Ministry of Health and Welfare., New Taipei City, Taiwan",
   "URL": "https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT04097652"
 },
 {
   "Rank": 4,
   "Title": "Curative Efficacy of Secondary Prevention for Patients With Ischemic Stroke Through Syndrome Differentiation of TCM",
   "Status": "Completed",
   "Study_Results": "No Results Available",
   "Conditions": "Ischemic Stroke",
   "Interventions": "Drug: Naoxintong Capsule|Drug: Placebo, Alteplase",
   "Locations": "Shanghai seventh People's Hospital, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Shanghai Ninth People's Hospital affliated to Shanghai Jiao Tong University Shool of Medcine, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|North Branch of Ruijin Hospital affliated to Shanghai Jiao Tong University, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Shanghai Putuo Central Hospital, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Shuguang Hospital affliated to Shanghai University of Traditional Chinese Medicine, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Longhua Hospital affliated to Shanghai University of Traditional Chinese Medicine, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Zhongshan Hospital affliated to Fudan University, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Huashan Hospital affliated to Fudan University, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Shanghai fifth People's Hospital affliated to Fudan University, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Tongren Hospital affliated to Shanghai Jiao Tong University, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Tongji Hospital, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Shanghai Chinese Medicine Hospital, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Shanghai tenth People's Hospital, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Shanghai Hospital of Integrative Medicine, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Xinhua Hospital affliated to Shanghai Jiao Tong University Shool of Medcine, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Dongfang Hospital affliated to Tongji University, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Pudong Gong Li Hospital of Shanghai, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Shanghai sixth People's Hospital affliated to Shanghai Jiao Tong University, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Changning Tongren Hospital of Shanghai, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Changhai Hospital, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Pudong Hospital of Traditional Chinese Medicine, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|East Branch of Shanghai sixth People's Hospital, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Qingpu Branch of Zhongshan Hospital affliated to Fudan University, Shanghai, Shanghai, China|Shanghai third People's Hospital affliated to Shanghai Jiao Tong University, Shanghai, Shanghai, China",
   "URL": "https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT02334969"
 },
]
```

What I need to do is parse the 'Interventions' Attribute for the following strings:

```
alt_aliases = ("Alteplase", "alteplase", "tpa", "t-PA", "tPA", "rtpa", "rtPA", "rt-PA", "r-tPA", "Rt-PA", "activase", "Activase")
```

If 'Interventions' contains 1 or more of these strings, I would like to return the 'Rank' value associated with the entry

I tried this but it did not work:

```
for key in data:
    if (data['Interventions'] == any(alt_aliases)):
        print(data['Rank'])
```

I realize that '==' will not work because there many possible strings that could be in that attribute but I am not sure how to use regex in python, especially with a dict like JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this using the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function to quickly check for a match with one of the aliases:

```
import json

json_filename = 'medical_data.json'
alt_aliases = ("Alteplase", "alteplase", "tpa", "t-PA", "tPA", "rtpa", "rtPA", "rt-PA",
               "r-tPA", "Rt-PA", "activase", "Activase")

with open(json_filename) as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for object in data:
    if any(alias in object['Interventions'] for alias in alt_aliases):
        print("Interventions: {Interventions} - Rank: {Rank}".format(**object))
```

Sample output:

```
Interventions: Drug: Naoxintong Capsule|Drug: Placebo, Alteplase - Rank: 4
```

**Alternative:**

This could also be done with the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) regular expression matching module, which can provide more powerful pattern matching operations should you need them — like ignoring letter-case — but that might be overkill for this relatively simple task.

```
import json
import re

json_filename = 'medical_data.json'
alt_aliases = ("Alteplase", "alteplase", "tpa", "t-PA", "tPA", "rtpa", "rtPA", "rt-PA",
               "r-tPA", "Rt-PA", "activase", "Activase")

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, alt_aliases))  # Construct pattern from aliases.
alias_regex = re.compile(pattern)

with open(json_filename) as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for object in data:
    if alias_regex.search(object['Interventions']):
        print("Interventions: {Interventions} - Rank: {Rank}".format(**object))
```

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, isn't object a reserved word, could I use anything here or does it have to be object?

Comment: Nope, `object` is not a reserved word. You can verify this via the `keyword` module: `keyword.iskeyword('object')` → `False`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want something like this:

```
# d stands for dictionary and lofd stands for list of dictionaries.
for d in lofd:
  if [_ for _ in alt_aliases if _ in d['Interventions']]:
    print(d)
```

Comment: This works! So a few questions as I am new to Python. Why are the underscores used in the if statement and is there anyway to just return a certain key:value instead of the entire entry?

Comment: Red: Using [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) to name variables isn't just unpythonic, it also has a number of disadvantages (see [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Disadvantages) in linked article).

Answer (score 0):

What `any()` does is it returns True if at least one of the elements in an iterable is true. This is kinda counter intuitive at first, because for this to work the way you want, you need to pass in a list of booleans.

So instead of `alt_aliases`, pass in something like `[True for alias in alt_aliases if alias in data['interventions']]`. This comprehended list should contain Trufor every alias you have in your data. If there is no alias there, list will be empty and `any()` will yield False.